# What could make a group of living organisms disappear completely from a closed structure?

Tags: aliens, planets, exploration

An alien pyramid had inhabitants trapped within. Without prospect for rescue, they eventually went mad. Later the pyramid is discovered by human explorers. No trace of the alien inhabitants or their prior habitation remains.

What could have happened that made the inhabitants of the pyramid disappear? What could make a group of living organisms disappear *completely* from a closed structure?

---

Those interested in the fine backstory can read it below, where it has been cleverly hidden!

> Location: *Mars, Eons ago  
> Many many years ago, Mars was not the dull and barren planet we know today. While not as abundant in fauna and flora as Earth, its many deserts were occasionally crowned with larger oases allowing life to flourish while at the same time being non-invasive. At this point in time parts of the planet are also inhabited by peaceful humanoid natives, tall but thin bipeds with a tight worn silky clothing that servers as a protective membrane against the scorching heat that can sometimes hit the surface. For the untrained observer, it might seem that the Martians are somewhere between the stone age and the iron age, but this could not be further from the truth. Indeed, they are capable of highly advanced space technology, have vast knowledge of Nature's laws, and they have managed to blend these technologies with Nature in an almost transparent way. 
>  For uncountable years the Martians lived in peace until now. A large-scale global cataclysmic event is predicted to happen within several years that has the potential to render the planet completely and utterly uninhabitable. The Martians devise a plan: they split their population into two groups, one that goes looking for help on other planets using their interplanetary orbs and another that stays behind, guarding all the knowledge and technology built throughout all these past eons. 
>  For this, they decide that the best structure to resist the cataclysm is the pyramid. It would have to be sealed from the outside, as the catastrophic event is predicted to destroy the livable atmosphere on the planet. There would have to be a minimal life-sustaining system and a means to hibernate for long periods of time. 
>  So they seal themselves in and begin to hibernate while their counterparts leave seeking for help. 
>  - Location: *Mars* - Time: *Several thousands of years after the event*
>   The hibernating Martians first come out of hibernation. They soon find out that the exit is still sealed and they have no way out. They reckon the search party either never found help or fell victim to an accident.  Desperate, they wander the stone halls in the darkness and soon lose their sanity.  
>  - Location: *Mars* - Time: *2050*  
>  Explorers from the Weyland-Musk Company from Earth form a base on Mars and begin terraforming. They soon stumble upon a strange pyramidal structure and decide to investigate it. Once they open it, and thouroughly search the premises, they find ... absolutely nothing. No signs that life was ever there, or that the place was built for any particular purpose. It's just ... empty.

---

Comment: How did the Martians deal with their dead?

Comment: isn't a whole pyramid a sign that life was there?

Comment: The half that went for help came back, gathered up everything, sealed up the door and went back to their new home.

Comment: This looks like a classic *"You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world."* example.

Comment: a too eager cleaning lady wiped the place clean?

Comment: Add the little word "apparently". They went looking there, they didn't find anything, but it's impossible to check for everything. They just didn't happen to find anything. If you want to know where your organisms went, just think of what they didn't or couldn't check for and the inhabitants turned into that, e.g. a pile of goo they didn't find or molecular traces they can't possibly pick up. And even if they find the pile of goo, who says that their interpretation was right? The people digging up the place might just have thrown it away with all the other rubble

Comment: It's quite obvious. Fungal spores carried inadvertently by the Soviet probes [Mars 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_6) and Mars 7 survived the unplanned lithobraking of the landers, and found their way into the cracks which had developed in the foundation of the pyramid during the aeons. As luck would have it, mutations induced by the harsh conditions of the interplanetary void made these spores find Martian corpses palatable; once all the available nourishment was consumed, the fungi dried up and were reduced to dust. The last frame of the movie shows an infected Weyland-Musk astronaut.

Comment: @AlexP lithobraking LOL, I like that!

Comment: This seems like a fine question.  The backstory is very cool and I think distracted the downvoters.  The question: how to make the pyramid empty on discovery despite the terrifying insanity that went on there centuries before.  I will take the liberty of editing to make the question more obvious, by putting it first.

Comment: To someone who voted reopen: how is this **world**building?

Comment: @Molot:  This is an allowed category of questions:  "How to achieve a specified effect in a defined world, including by the use of biology, technology or magic, while maintaining in-universe consistency".  I found the text here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Willk stories are off topic. Effects in worlds mean things like formation of planetary rings, global cataclysmic events, changes in global politics etc. **World** effects, not stories in worlds.

Comment: What does 'disappear completely' mean? There are a lot of possible milestones that might be considered 'completely' gone. Is the pyramid still visible? Inside, is there merely no bones and no bodies, or no bio matter at all and no artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Something finds its way in to the survivors and does away with them**.  Your premise reminded me of the Vaults of Yoh-Vombis, a story by Clark Ashton Smith which involves the exploration of abandoned Martian ruins.
   http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/short-stories/229/the-vaults-of-yoh-vombis-%28abridged%29

> "There's a story, isn't there," said Harper, "that the last remnant of
>   the Yorhis was destroyed by some unknown agency—something too horrible
>   and outré to be mentioned even in a myth?"
>
> "Of course, I've heard that legend," agreed Octave. "Maybe we'll find
>   evidence among the ruins to prove or disprove it. The Yorhis may have
>   been cleaned out by some terrible epidemic, such as the Yashta
>   pestilence, which was a kind of green mould that ate all the bones of
>   the body, together with the teeth and nails. But we needn't be afraid
>   of getting it, if there are any mummies in Yoh-Vombis—the bacteria
>   will all be as dead as their victims, after so many cycles of
>   planetary desiccation."

What they find is not at all dead.  Fun read!  This would be a creepy approach to the problem.

**2.  The survivors go down into the earth.**
Maddened by their inability to escape, the survivors move downwards, cutting their way into the Earth.  Maybe they find refuge of a sort down there.  Maybe they find something else below the pyramid.  They might be down there still.  Also a creepy approach.

**3.  Dimensional shift.**  There is Martian precedent here in the works of Heinlein.
http://www.heinleinsociety.org/rah/works/articles/heinleins_mars.html

> Here the giant Martians encircle a transgressor, "mov[ing] in slowly,
>   tightening the circle" until he is "completely concealed from the
>   spectators by a screen of palm flaps," and though his protesting voice
>   may "[stop] in a scream," when the Martians disperse there is "not
>   even a spot of blood on the floor" (180-81).
>
> Such "disappearing" also is used defensively numerous times in
>   Stranger in a Strange Land, where it finally is described as pushing
>   the person--or other object--"perpendicular" to our three dimensions.
>   When Robert Plank claims that Mike's "disappearing" tactic sometimes
>   "amounts to mass murder", he is ostensibly correct, but this quick
>   critical judgment also oversimplifies the issue by ignoring two
>   important points: the tactic is used here only for immediate defense,
>   and, after two instances of Mike's panicked destruction of armed,
>   albeit uniformed, intruders who threaten him and his benefactors, in
>   later moments of crisis he carefully attempts to "disappear" only
>   weapons, not their bearers.

It is not clear where the disappeared go.  It may be to another dimension or another time or both.  It is clear that some aspects of the Martians survive their "deaths" to have meaningful interactions with the living at a later time.  When the Martians decide to disappear this is how they do it.

This would be the cleanest way to have everything go - the Martians and their things give up on this plane and move off to a different plane of being.  Less creepy I think.

4. **They are still there but the explorers do not perceive them.**

I am thinking of the hyperdimensional mall in Valerian and the City of 1000 Planets.
https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/26/16027946/big-market-valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets-virtual-reality-shopping

Stuff is there and some stuff shares our space but not all.  The martian world overlaps with ours but not completely.  Maybe we never would have been able to see these beings without the correct equipment.  Not too creepy.

Answer (score 1):

Time travel, they went so insane they figured it out.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46477)

Comment: The question asks how did they disappear, this is one method by which they could disappear. If that does not qualify as an answer, then nothing else does either.